# do dart streams come with extra overhead?

Tags: dart, stream

I have a general efficiency question about dart streams.

I have a project that makes some use of them, but it has been proposed that we convert nearly everything (functions and data) to be dart streams. This is in order to achieve a fully reactive architecture.

I don't know how streams really work under the hood, so I don't really know if this kind of design comes with any kind of memory or computational overhead.

Thanks for your attention to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There *is* an overhead. It's not necessarily big, but it's there.

Streams have a well-defined asynchronous behavior, and it's documented how they react to listeners being added, paused or cancelled, even if that happens while an event is being delivered (because, most often, that is when it happens).

Streams are *asynchronous*, which means there is a delay between adding an event to the stream (through a `StreamController`), and that event being received by the listener. That delay makes it necessary to store (buffer) the event, schedule a microtask, and then unbuffer the event and deliver it in that later microtask. Scheduling a microtask costs. There might be zones involved, which can cost extra.

On top of that, because the stream needs to be able to react to `pause` and `cancel` events in a timely manner, which means that each event delivery is also flanked by extra checks of whether the event handler has paused or cancelled. It's not a lot of overhead, but it's there.

For single-subscription streams, that's about it.

For broadcast streams, which can have multiple listeners, there can be a little extra overhead to handle new listeners being added *while* delivering the event. Again, not a lot, but it's there. The state-space for a stream is actually quite complicated.

(You can create "a synchoronous `StreamController`" which delivers events "immediately", but most of the time, you *shouldn't*. Those are not for avoiding asynchrony, they are for avoiding adding *extra* asynchronous delays when propagating already synchronous events, and should be used very carefully to avoid breaking code assuming that they won't get events in the middle of something else. A properly implemented reactive framework will use such controllers in their implementation, but that will not get rid of the original inherent delay of delivering the original asynchronous event.)

Now, performance is not absolute. Using streams everywhere might make your life easier, and if the performance is *good enough* for your application (it's not dominating the actual computations), then the increased development speed and maintainability might pay for itself. You should *measure* (and have repeatable benchmarks to measure) before making a decision about an implementation strategy based on performance alone.